Bridging two networks using Ubuntu
Good afternoon,
I would like to try combining two networks using Ubuntu. More specifically, I have a DJI Tello drone, which generates its own Wi-Fi access point, and therefore the devices connected to its own Wi-Fi access point can only control the drone. However, what I would like to achieve is to connect this drone via Ubuntu as a bridge to my router, so that I can control the drone from other devices connected to the router, or using public IP by port forwarding.
Here's the current configuration.
Drone's access point (IP and settings cannot be altered) - wireless connection to Ubuntu (Blue line in the diagram)

Drone's address: 192.168.10.1
Ubuntu's address connected to the drone: 192.168.10.3
Default route from Ubuntu's side: 192.168.10.1

Router's access point (IP and settings can be altered) - wired connection to Ubuntu and wireless connection to other devices (Purple line in the diagram)

Router's (configuration page) address: 192.168.10.100
Ubuntu's address connected to the router: 192.168.10.51
Default route from Ubuntu's side: 192.168.10.100


If I can access the drone with its IP 192.168.10.1 from another devices connected to the router, I guess I can also do port forwarding or DMZ from the drone's IP to the public IP, so that I can access drone also from the external internet.
What I have done
I've installed the bridge-utils package to the Ubuntu, then set up the bridge interface as the above configuration via GUI. However, unless I manually adjust the metrics for the drone's wireless connection lower, I could not ping to 192.168.10.1 (drone). If I adjust the metrics value, then I could ping to both drone (192.168.10.1) and router (192.168.10.100) successfully. Unfortunately, when I tried to access the drone with its ip 192.168.10.1 from the other device attached to the router (MacBook), it says that there is no route to host.
Since the final goal is to access drone from the external internet, I would be glad to hear if there will be any configuration that I can adjust from Ubuntu's (or even Router's) side, so that virtually the drone is connected to the router as a client with its IP address, 192.168.10.1.
Any help will be appreciated.

You've not said what release you're asking about; but have tagged an EOL/EOSS release that is off-topic on this site.  Ubuntu product/release details help us know what networking software you're using; NetworkManager, Netplan etc...

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Yes, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but would be glad to update its distro. I am just using it because that's what I have now. Also, I am using default Network Manager GUI.

As there are two hosts handing out IP addresses, and you cannot change that, the two networks must be connected by a router to translate addresses. The Ubuntu system can act as a router. Avoid the term "bridge," as the networking term bridge has a different meaning.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will release-upgrade to 18.04 which is EOSS as well (or EOL depending on unstated architecture) and also off-topic here, so you'd need to be on 18.04 and be asking about a release-upgrade to 20.04 (the oldest on-topic release on this site) for help. Canonical provide support for releases (16.04 for example) that is in extended support; as Ubuntu support covered you only the first five years of standard support (until 2021 for 16.04, 2023 for 18.04)

You may find it easier to fresh install 24.04 rather than doing multiple upgrades.

Thank you very much for your help.
@user535733 I didn't know that the term bridging can mean different thing.
